# Imgproc.FindContours не заполняет List<MatOfPoint> контуров Opencv Android

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin, monodroid

Использую OpenCV4Android версии 2.4.11 (разработка ведется под Xamarin.Android).
Я пытаюсь найти **Границы** прямоугольного объекта(лист бумаги формата А4) посредством OpenCV. 
Пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм:
Canny edge -> Largest contour -> largest rectangle -> find corners -> perspective change.

Вот мой код:

```
using(Bitmap _img = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(App._file.Path)) {
    if (_img != null) {
        m = new Mat();
        grayM = new Mat();

        Utils.BitmapToMat(_img, m);
        //apply filter
        Imgproc.Canny(m, m, 100, 100, 3, true);
        //gaus Blur
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(m, m, new Org.Opencv.Core.Size(5, 5), 5);
        //list for contours
        List < MatOfPoint > Contours = new List < MatOfPoint > ();
        Mat hierarcy = new Mat();
        //our method to find contours,via filling List(Contours)
        Imgproc.FindContours(m, Contours, hierarcy, Imgproc.RetrList, Imgproc.ChainApproxSimple);

        System.Console.WriteLine(Contours.Count + " Contours founded");
        //Dont know why,but Contours list is always empty(no values)
        if (Contours.Count != 0) {
            MatOfPoint temp = Contours[0];
        }
    }
```

И тут я застрял, потому что не понимаю, почему **FindContours** не заполняет значениями мой список `List<MatOfPoint>`(всегда пустой).
Перепробовал наверное все,все равно не хочет.
В чем же может быть проблема?

Так же,довольно странная проблема:
Исходное изображение #1
[image: Source Image]
если я использую только такие методы, как **Imgproc.Canny** и **Imgproc.GaussianBlur** , то тогда результат выглядит примерно так(контуры обведены отлично):
[image: Canny with GaussianBlur]

В противном случае,а именно когда я использую метод **Imgproc.FindContours**,то результат выглядит гораздо хуже,ежели без использования самого метода(нахождения контуров),к тому же List он не заполняет,т.е. лист остается пустым,после инициализации:
[image: With Imgproc.FindContours]

Другое исходное изображение #2:
[image: Source Image 2]
без использования метода **Imgproc.FindContours**(только **Imgproc.Canny** вместе с **Imgproc.GaussianBlur**) :
[image: w/o FindContours]
а здесь уже применяется **FindContours** метод :
[image: with Contours]

Все же не могу понять,где моя ***ошибка***. Может кто то подсказать\объяснить что я делаю не так,а так же как мне достичь моей цели?
Заранее благодарю!

PPS позже выложу результаты альтернативных алгоритмов(к примеру,через HoughLinesP или FeatureDetector.Fast)

Comment: Попробуйте бинаризовать (threshold) результат после гаусса и кэнни. И метод `findContours()` модифицирует поданную на вход матрицу. Необходимо работать с копией, если требуется сохранить оригинал исходника.

Comment: @alexis031182 пробовал,не помогает,все равно лист пустой...

Comment: @alexis031182 я грешу на Xamarin,ибо испробовал наверное все что возможно.

Comment: очень похоже, что Вы правы, т.к. плюсовый `findCountours()` всегда находит контуры, будь у них значение пикселя равно единице (т.е. больше нуля) и размер хотя бы в несколько пикселей.

Comment: @alexis031182 Я создал проект в нативной форме(java + Android Studio). Все работает как часы, метод FindContours заполняет лист,изображение (квадратного типа) находится на ура(в отличии моих методов,которые я испробовал при помощи HoughLinesP).Остается два пути : 1) попробовать установить еще раз OpenCV 3.0.0 в мой проект(на Xamarin'e); 2)Вытащить этот класс,созданный посредством жавы и забиндить в проект, как враппер.

Comment: К сожалению не могу помочь с выбором, т.к. работал только с C++ API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того как было потрачено куча времени,я пришел к выводу,что это просто напросто ***Баг***, т.к. скорей всего не корректно спортировался этот метод(а что именно не так встало,не понятно).
Решением проблемы может быть:

1. Установка новой версии(к примеру **OpenCV 3.0.0**).
2. Заимплементить **Java Wrapper** класс,который можно будет подключить к проекту и успешно юзать(через мир Java'ы).

Такие вот дела.

PS в нативной форме все работает как часы.